# Will a WPF ListView be populated if its Visibility is set to Collapsed

Tags: wpf, listview

If I had a really large ListView whose `Visiblity` were set to `Collapsed`, would it populate during `InitializeComponent()` or only if the `Visiblity` were changed to `Visible`?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I should have mentioned, in my scenario, the ListView would be populated via bindings. I want to know if there will be a performance hit to having a ListView with a lot of data even if it is never shown.

Comment: Can't you just put a break point in wherever you provide the data for the listview to see if it gets hit when the form is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be populated. Even popups or tool tips are created before they are shown. If this turns out to be an issue you can lazy load the control in code behind when a certain action occurs.

You could use a placeholder like a ContentPresenter

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="listHost"/>
```

and then set the Content property to a new instance of the list control when a certain action happens.

Somewhere in code behind

```
var listView = new ListView(); 
//set up bindings... populate the listView 
listHost.Content = listView;
```